# What does "Failed to parse SourceMap:" mean in devTools?

Tags: javascript, css

Chrome devTools keeps popping up this error `Failed to parse SourceMap:` in the console, and I don't know what it's referring to. Is it something I should be worried about?

Comment: This keeps coming in Chrome and it seems this is a known issue with Chrome (Issue: 1447433003). Asking questions should not be discouraged - disagree with the down votes.

Comment: Completely agree, this is a real issue. This is not "unclear" at all.